# Google Search Console API permission error

Tags: python, google-api, google-search-console

I am completely newbie in automation for SEO, as well as in Python as well. Expectedly, I faced several issues building my first automation, so any help is appreciated.

**Description on my issue**
I need to export data from Google search console for a selected URLs list. Actually there are 400+ URLs, so I definitely don’t want to do it manually. Also this is a repeated exercise, so I don’t want to do it in 3 months period even more.

**The way I’ve chosen**
I decided to write a simple Python Script using Google Search Console API. I’ve created a separate project in Google Cloud, generated Credentials, set up an Oauth Consent Screen for Desktop App. I ensured, that this app has a right scopes (/webmaster and /webmasters.readonly). In my script I used the right Client_ID and Client_Secret, but every time I run my script it returns Error - “User doesn’t have sufficient permission for this site…”. I am a verified GSC project owner, all Google Cloud steps seems to be set up correctly, but for some unclear reason I cannot perform data export via API.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
 import csv
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

CLIENT_ID = 'your_client_id'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'your_client_secret'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly']
JSON_FILE_PATH = 'path_to_your_downloaded_json_file.json'

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(JSON_FILE_PATH, SCOPES)
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

service = build('webmasters', 'v3', credentials=creds)

urls = [
    'https://example.com/page1',
    'https://example.com/page2',
]

data = []

for url in urls:
    request = {
        'startDate': 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        'endDate': 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        'dimensions': ['page', 'query'],
        'rowLimit': 15,
        'startRow': 0,
        'aggregationType': 'auto',
        'searchType': 'web',
        'dimensionFilterGroups': [
            {
                'filters': [
                    {'dimension': 'page', 'operator': 'equals', 'expression': url}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    response = service.searchanalytics().query(siteUrl=url, body=request).execute()

    for row in response.get('rows', []):
        keyword = row['keys'][1]
        clicks = row['clicks']
        impressions = row['impressions']
        ctr = row['ctr']
        position = row['position']
        data.append((url, keyword, clicks, impressions, ctr, position))

sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[3], reverse=True)

output_csv_file = 'search_console_data.csv'
with open(output_csv_file, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_writer.writerow(['URL', 'Keyword', 'Clicks', 'Impressions', 'CTR', 'Position'])
    csv_writer.writerows(sorted_data)

print(f'Data exported to {output_csv_file}')
```

Comment: Can you share `simple Python Script ` and screen shut of error?

Comment: Hi Bench! 
I've edited my description and added code sample

Error is following:
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting {API Endpoint URL} returned "User does not have sufficient permission for site 'example.com'